# Bash boolean variable check says command not found

Tags: bash, macos, shell

I have a shell script with `.sh` extension & running in OSX environment where I have set up a variable like below:

```
booean_var1 = false
booean_var2 = true
```

And there an if check based on the 2 variables

```
if [ $booean_var1 ] || [ $booean_var2 ]
then
  echo one of them is true
fi
```

Running it on bash on one OSX machine works fine. But I executed my shell script from another OSX machine & running it on bash from there says

```
booean_var1 command not found
```

**Does shell script syntax differ from on bash from one machine to another ?**

Comment: Remove space around `=`

Comment: `[ ]` doesn't test if a string equals `true`, only if it is non-empty.

Comment: `bash` doesn't have Boolean constants. `true` and `false` are names of commands.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try without spaces:

```
booean_var1=false
booean_var2=true
```

And because `true` and `false` are commands:

```
which true false
/bin/true
/bin/false
```

You could simply whipe brackets `[`, `]`:

```
if $booean_var1 || $booean_var2 ;then
    echo one of them is true
fi
```

Comment: You have to **not** use spaces for assignment! Ses `PARAMETERS` in bash's man page! `man -Pless\ +/^PARAMETERS bash`

Answer (score 2):

```
booean_var1=false
booean_var2=true

if [ "$booean_var1" = true ] || [ "$booean_var2" = true ]
then
  echo one of them is true
fi
```